# Microsoft Graph Update User Relevant Permissions Not Working

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to make an Update User call. I have provided delegated User.ReadWrite permissions to my application and I have obtained a token as the user to be updated. Here is the URL I am making the PATCH call to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com
```

Regardless of what property I attempt to edit, I get this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-11T11:41:26",
            "request-id": REDACTED,
            "client-request-id": REDACTED
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my sample body:

```
{
  "officeLocation": "city-value"
}
```

Could this have nothing to do with my permissions but rather be a result of some of the settings in my tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the [User Administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#user-administrator-permissions) to the signed in user or service principal.

Comment: Is this the only way to make the Update User API call functional? To have the signed in user in an administrative role? Is there no way to allow users without an administrative role to update properties on their record with this call?

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your problem:

[image]

If you only have delegated User.ReadWrite permissions are not enough, you need to grant the application **User.ReadWrite.All** delegated permissions.(Don't forget to grant **admin consent** for this permission).

[image]

PS: You need to be aware that when you try to update different property, you may need higher permissions. For example, when you need to update the **passwordProfile** property, you need the following permissions: Directory.AccessAsUser.All.  see: [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Adding this permission did not make a difference. The token retrieved via OAuth2.0 was associated with an account that does not have administrative role. We are looking for users to be able to update their own passwords and not anyone else's. So if an admin role is required, I'm afraid the Update User functionality is a bust for us.

Comment: @RedXXVI  Unfortunately, users cannot change their own passwords, and only administrators can change their own or users' passwords. This is the only way!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the "client_credential" grant type to fetch the access token instead of sign in user, and I also encounter the "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" upon updating a user account today.

Here is what I find and solve the issue for now,

The application I use has the following permissions consented.

[image]

And I noticed that the user I am trying to update has some "Administrative role" that this application doesn't have.

[image]

Then I go to "Azure ActiveDirectory" > "Roles and Administrators", find the role and click it. And then click "Add assignments", and choose the application you use for your process.

[image]

After successfully assign the role, you will see the app is added to this role with a type called "ServicePrincipal".

[image]

After that, wait for around 2 mins, I can redo the PATCH call and update the user.

[image]

=======================================================

Even though this solves my issue, but I don't know whether it is the correct approach. Because following this solution, there will be one issue that:

1. If this user has multiple roles, then you have to either add this application to every role or directly assign the application to "Global Administrator".

I don't have a good/elegant solution for this. If you know anything or you have another solution, please let me know.